# Extract text from image or real time video streaming

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5, python-tesseract, automatic-license-plate-recognition

`Extract text from image`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Path to Tesseract executable (change this according to your installation)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# Load the image
image_path = r'D:\image\image3.png'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Check if the image was loaded successfully
if image is None:
    print("Failed to load the image:", image_path)
    exit(1)

# Continue with image processing
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, sharpen_kernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
result = 255 - close

# Display the processed images
cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('result', result)

# Perform OCR
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray)

# Print the extracted text
print("Extracted Text:")
print(text)

# Display the original image
cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`Extract text from real time video streaming`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import cv2


class FrameGrabber(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FrameGrabber, self).__init__(parent)

    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QImage)

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
        while cap.isOpened():
            success, frame = cap.read()
            if success:
                image = QtGui.QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_BGR888)
                self.signal.emit(image)

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        self.MainWindow = MainWindow
        self.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        self.grabber = FrameGrabber()
        self.grabber.signal.connect(self.updateFrame)
        self.grabber.start()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(840, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.imglabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.imglabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 480))
        self.imglabel.setObjectName("imglabel")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 0, 200, 480))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(15)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Plate', 'Registration', 'Sanc'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QImage)
    def updateFrame(self, image):
        self.imglabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Stationnement"))

    def appExec(self):
        self.grabber.appExec()

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am trying to extract the text from the image, that was a first try, if it work then I will apply the technique to real time video straming, but both failed, I failed to extract the text from the image, at the same time I have code the real time video streaming to extract the text from live, I only success to connect to laptop web camera only, I dont know how to write the coding for real time license plate recognition, I totally have no idea how to do the next, may somebody guide me for that